# No completition of Cartesian Path using Moveit

Tags: ros, joint, moveit, ur10, limits

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

I have a question regarding planning with a UR10 arm and Moveit. I try to compute a Cartesian Path around an object. And it frequently happens that the robot can not successfully follow the path until 100%. E.g. it stops after 59% etc. Looking on the control panel for the robot, I noticed that it could not execute the path completely because a joint limit is reached (-2 pi/2 pi). It is a little bit strange to me because normally Moveit should know that it will violate that limit and of course just setting the start state to something around 0 degree would do the job, but it starts for example sometimes with 250 degree for that special joint. Could you help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Hannes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255866/no-completition-of-cartesian-path-using-moveit/) by [HannesIII](https://answers.ros.org/users/28698/hannesiii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current cartesian path planning in MoveIt is quite limited.
Your specific example confuses me though. To use the `GetCartesianPath` ROS service, *you* have to provide the start state. If MoveIt were allowed to decide on a start-state, this would most likely end up in a non-cartesian trajectory to reach the start state first of all.

If you need further capabilities, have a look at the [decartes](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes) project.
We are currently discussing to integrate this into standard MoveIt.
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/467

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HannesIII](https://answers.ros.org/users/28698/hannesiii/) on 2017-04-11**:
Sorry for my late response, wasn't able to get in.
The problem is that the robot can reach a state using different joint values. E.g. one joint value can be 20 deg or 200deg (+180deg). So my solution would be to tell the robot to use a value between [-180,180] for a pose. How can I do that?